# SDL Mixer Sound Not Playing

Tags: c++, sdl

I am making a game using SDL and my SoundHandler class is not working and I cannot figure out why. The file paths are definatly correct and I have SDL_Mixer set up properly as I have had sound work correctly before, I also get no errors or warnings the game runs fine there is just no music.

SoundHandler.h:

```
enum Sounds
{
    BACKGROUND_MUSIC, STICK_COLLECT
};

class SoundHandler
{
    public:
        SoundHandler();
        void PlaySound(Sounds sound);
    private:
        Mix_Music *backMusic;
        Mix_Music *stickCollect;
};
```

SoundHandler.cpp:

```
SoundHandler::SoundHandler()
{
    Mix_OpenAudio(22050, MIX_DEFAULT_FORMAT, 2, 4096);
    this->backMusic = Mix_LoadMUS("Data//Music//Background.mp3");
    this->stickCollect = Mix_LoadMUS("Data//Sounds//StickCollect.mp3");
    Mix_VolumeMusic(128);
}

void SoundHandler::PlaySound(Sounds sound)
{
    if(sound == BACKGROUND_MUSIC)
    {
        Mix_PlayMusic(this->backMusic, -1);
    }
    if(sound == STICK_COLLECT)
    {
        Mix_PlayMusic(this->stickCollect, 1);
    }
}
```

Relevant Lines in main.cpp:

```
// Initialise Sound
SoundHandler soundHandler;

// Play Background Music
soundHandler.PlaySound(BACKGROUND_MUSIC);

// Play Sound
soundHandler.PlaySound(STICK_COLLECT);
```

Comment: Are you doing any error checking or is this your full code? Any of `Mix_` functions may be silently failing. I'd start by making sure that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is in double slashes in file path, try to use single slash.

You will have long time of debugging without error checking.